# Simple Injector registers only one parameter of a class having multi-parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm a part of team creating a "sort of" message based framework where people can register their message handlers with the dependencies they have for their handlers.

[image: IDependencyResolver concept]

The worker, will receive messages and invoke relevant handlers. Since the handlers have dependencies so we are passing **IDependecyResolver** implementation through the worker constructor. Worker uses this abstraction to create these handlers.

The users of our framework can use any DI container they like so all they have to do is to implement certain interfaces that provide abstraction to their favorite DI container. My job is to provide an implementation for SimpleInjector so for our framework, SimpleInjector is supported out of box.

The problem I'm facing is that even though I register an **SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver** in the container, the container is not able to resolve IDependencyResolver implementation at runtime and I get this.

This is the exception I get.

> ActivationException: The constructor of type ReactiveWorker<HelloModuleBase> contains the parameter with name 'map' and type IMessageHandlerMap<HelloModuleBase> that is not registered. Please ensure IMessageHandlerMap<HelloModuleBase> is registered, or change the constructor of ReactiveWorker<HelloModuleBase>.

Here is my code for registration:

```cs
registrant.Register<IDependencyResolver>(LifeSpan.Scoped);
registrant.Register<IMessageHandlerMap<TChildModule>>(t0, LifeSpan.Scoped);
```

the worker needs both, a message-handler map and a dependency resolver.

[image]

This is my class with parameterized constructors:

```cs
public sealed class ReactiveWorker<TOwnerModule>: IWorker
{
    readonly IMessageHandlerMap<TOwnerModule> _map;
    readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public ReactiveWorker(IMessageHandlerMap<TOwnerModule> map, IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        _map = map;
        _resolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

I hope everyone is able to understand the scenario.

Comment: From the code you posted, it seems to me that you are trying to recreate functionality that Simple Injector does for you out of the box. Unfortunately, the limited amount of code you posted makes it very hard to understand what it is you are trying to achieve. Can you update your question and provide us with the following information: 1) describe what problem you are trying to solve with your registration. 2) Show the structure of your application (interface and class definitions) of the code related to your question (e.g. show `MessageHandlerMap`).

Comment: @Steven I updated the question so you could understand the scenario better. The reason for posting less amount of code is simply due to company policy. I can only expose a very limited amount of code and that's the most i could manage, so instead i used diagrams to make the question more understandable. I hope you'll find the updated version more understandable, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create an abstract class/layer for all dependency resolvers which are/will be used in my project.

This sure sounds like you are applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). You might want to double check if what you're doing is Dependency Injection or Service Location and prevent Service Location whenever possible.

Furthermore, from the posted registrations, it looks like if you are trying to implement batch-registration behavior. Simple Injector does contain this functionality out of the box, and it is worth investing into Simple Injector's API to see whether you can let the tooling do the job.

Your `Helper.FindConcreteImplementationsOf`, for instance, looks a lot like Simple Injector's `Container.GetTypesToRegister` method. It returns concrete implementations of a given type, for instance:

```cs
Type[] types = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IMessageHandler<>), asm);
```

Simple Injector also allows for mapping open-generic abstractions to open-generic implementations. Using your `MessageHandlerMap<T>`, for instance, you can do the following:

```cs
container.Register(
    typeof(IMessageHandlerMap<>),
    typeof(MessageHandlerMap<>),
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

This ensures that a closed version of `MessageHandlerMap<T>` is created, every time a closed version of `IMessageHandlerMap<T>` is requested. This does, however, rely on Simple Injector's Auto-Wiring ability, which means that Simple Injector must be able to inject all dependencies into the class's  constructor. This might mean you have to change the constructor of `MessageHandlerMap<T>` in order to let Simple Injector Auto-Wire the type.

Because its unclear to me what the function of `MessageHandlerMap<T>` is and how its implementation looks like, I'm unable to fully grasp what you're trying to achieve, and can't, therefore, not give you more specific advise about making changes to your design.

Good luck.

Comment: I re-edited my question with someone's help. I hope it is more clear. Also do you still think it is an anti-pattern? If so, what is your recommendation in this case?

Comment: I re-read your question. You should read this https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/ to double check if your design is sane.